# Umbraco throws stackoverflow exception when run from SVN checkout folder

Tags: svn, umbraco, stack-overflow, umbraco5

This might sound silly, but my umbraco 5.1 application (after upgrading from 5.0) simply throws a stackoverflow exception and crashes the IIS/IIS express when run from the checked out folder (with svn hidden items)

But when I do an svn export (to avoid svn structure) and run from exported folders (without svn hidden folders etc), it works like a charm. Could umbraco be fighting with the SVN folder structure somehow?

I am using Visual studio 2010 ultimate, SQL 2008, used Nuget to upgrade my application from Umbraco 5.0x to 5.1, and tried running on WIndows 2003/windows7 environments with the same results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to svn 1.7 ([Release notes](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html)), and take advantage of "Centralized Metadata Storage" (default in 1.7), where you don't have any .svn folders, in all the subfolders, but one large one.

Its the new standard, and you don't have to fight that **damn** hidden folders